# How to query custom post type one after another

Tags: query

I am trying to query my custom post types. I can display both of them with this code:

`'post_type'=> array('map','item')`

But I don't want them to mix. I want "map" to display before "item".

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 4.0 is available [`'type'` option for `'orderby'` argument](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) in `WP_Query`.

Also, thanks to the [more powerful ORDER BY in WordPress 4.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/08/29/a-more-powerful-order-by-in-wordpress-4-0/) you can control how posts of a post type are ordered.

Example (untested):

```
$q = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => array('map','item'),
    'orderby'   => array(
       'type'   => 'DESC',
       'title'  => 'ASC'
    )
));
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I had to add `remove_all_filters('posts_orderby');` before it in my case!

Comment: Glad it worked. Please mark the answer as accepted if it was right solution for you.